# Suppress backspace, delete keys in MaskedTextbox

Tags: c#, winforms

The question is simple: how to do it?
I've a couple of MaskedTextboxes which are filled by some indirect user actions (so not by typing in values directly). The text within the textboxes is colored red when the input is being rejected by the mask. Fine so far.

However, I don't want the end-user to be able to edit the boxes directly. So, I added the following code:

```
    private void HandleMaskedTextBoxKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void HandleMaskedTextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
```

And while most characters are handled, the backspace and delete keys aren't: text disappears when pressing those keys. How can those keys be handled, too?

(Another option would be to set the `readonly` property of the boxes to `true`, but then the  text doesn't get colored red anymore when input is rejected. I tried to force the red color in the `MaskInputRejected` event, but this didn't work out, either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to set the `MaskedTextBox`'s `ReadOnly` property to `true`. But instead of handling the `MaskInputRejected` event, you should use the `TypeValidationCompleted` event like this:

```
private void maskedTextBox1_TypeValidationCompleted(object sender, TypeValidationEventArgs e) {
  maskedTextBox1.ForeColor = e.IsValidInput ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
}
```

Since I guess you're modifying the value of the `MaskedTextBox` by code, you'll have to also handle the `TextChanged` event to trigger a validation like this:

```
private void maskedTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  maskedTextBox1.ValidateText();
}
```

Finally (and this is key), since the `MaskedTextBox` will be read only, you'll want to set the `BackColor` and `ForeColor` properties back to `Color.White` and `Color.Black` respectively, but you'll have to do it in code, in the constructor of the form for instance...

```
maskedTextBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
maskedTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

If you have a lot of them, I suggest you create a new control that inherits from `MasketTextBox` and override those values.

Comment: Interesting solution, however, the maskedTextBox1_TypeValidationCompleted isn't fired after maskedTextBox1.ValidateText(), so the color still doesn't get red.

Comment: Actually, it does (I took a look at it using Reflector), did set the BackColor to Color.White? Because it is true that it doesn't work if you don't do that... As to why, I have no idea!

Comment: I had to set the ValidatingType property on the textbox. It works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a richtextbox. Set read only to true, and mask the chars with the code beind.

I hope that helps.
 RG